# What is the Laplace transform of the following integral?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I want to find the Laplace transform of the integral $$\int_0^1 (x-t)u(t)dt$$

The integral resembles a convolution but it is not, since the convolution would be $$\int_0^x (x-t)u(t)dt$$, whose Laplace transform is well known.

I tried splitting the integral as follows $$\int_0^1 (x-t)u(t)dt =\int_0^x (x-t)u(t)dt -\int_1^x (x-t)u(t)dt$$
now the first term is a convolution but the second one has a lower limit of $1$ rather than $0$, so it's not a convolution.

So what should I do to find the Laplace transform of this integral?

Comment: In your convolution (formula 2) how do you integrate against t with t as a limit?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a typo.

Comment: What $u(t)$ is for here? It does not appear to do anything.

Comment: Laplace ransform is usually applied to a function. Do you mean your integral to be a function of $x$ and Laplace transform with respect to $x$?

Comment: Yes I want the Laplace transform with respect to $x$. $u$ is just some function.